# MCP3561 Configuration registers resetting upon relay activation

Tags: power-supply, relay, adc, load-cell

I am looking for advice on how to solve a problem I'm encountering with my PCB project. The application involves reading a weight from a cluster of load cells and activating a relay that controls a solenoid valve should the weight fall below a given threshold. To that end, I am using an MCP3561 to handle the analog-to-digital conversion, a SAMD20G MCU for processing, and an Omron G5V-1 24V relay. The board is powered by mains voltage which is stepped down to 24VDC using a Mean Well IRM-10 switching power supply (PS1). The 24VDC output of PS1 is stepped down to 3.3VDC using a Recom R-78E3.3-1.0 (PS2) to power the MCU and the digital side of the ADC. An ON Semi LP2950CZ-3.3 linear regulator (PS3) provides power for the load cell excitation voltage and the analog side of the ADC. The ground planes for each power supply are tied together at the ground terminal of PS1. Schematic 1 depicts these power supplies. Schematic 2 depicts the ADC and load cell portion of the circuit. Schematic 3 shows the relay circuitry.

The problem I'm encountering occurs when the relay is triggered and a load is attached to its output. For testing purposes, I have attached a small fish tank pump to the relay output. The relay acts as a contact closure for L2 such that when the relay coil is energized, continuity is established and power flows from L1 through the pump to L2. The configuration registers of the ADC chip get reset to their default values when this occurs. This results in the ADC entering shutdown mode.

In an attempt to remedy this problem, I've included a section of code that checks the intersample interval of the ADC (time between successive data ready interrupts). Should that interval be too long, the code checks the configuration registers and reinitializes the ADC if needed. It appears to have resolved the symptoms of the problem, but I would like to correct the underlying issue before moving forward.

I should also include that the device functions properly without a load attached to the relay output. My best guess is that the inductive load of the pump motor is causing significant noise in the power supply to the ADC which is forcing a reset of the chip. I lock the registers during configuration to prevent any erroneous writes to the registers. When the error occurs, the registers always revert to their default values.

In addition to the code fix I described earlier, I've attempted a few electrical fixes as well: I replaced the ADC chip and I tried to increase the bypass capacitance of the ADC supply lines by adding an additional 10uF tantalum capacitor in parallel with the two caps already present on either supply line. Neither of these changes had any effect. I've contemplated including a snubber with the relay, but I am not certain of what R/C values to use nor how to retrofit such a change on a mostly SMD PCB.

To be exhaustive, I have also included a few screenshots of the PCB layout.

Any feedback you could provide would be very much appreciated. I am a new engineer and I'm trying to learn everything I can, so please forgive any errors I might have made either in the formatting of this question, the design of my circuit/PCB, or my troubleshooting steps.

Thank you in advance!

Schematic 1: Power Supplies
[image: Schematic 1]

Schematic 2: ADC and Load Cells
[image: Schematic 2]

Schematic 3: Relay Circuit
[image: Schematic 3]

PCB 1: ADC
[image: ADC]

PCB 2: Relay
[image: Relay]

Comment: How did you pick your decoupling caps? 10uF seems very high, and they should probably be X5R's or X7R's, it looks like you are using polarized? Also, how is your GND connected to the earth ground?

Comment: The MCP3561 datasheet states that a 10uF should be placed in parallel with a 0.1uF on both DVDD and AVDD (sections 3.7 and 3.8, respectively). My apologies: the cap symbols on the schematic are incorrect. They are actually MLCC X5Rs. Earth ground is currently not connected to the ground planes on the PCB.

Comment: So your dc ground is floating?

Comment: I suppose it is floating in the sense that it is not connected to the earth ground. This is likely my inexperience talking, but I was under the assumption that earth ground did not need to be connected to the ground terminal of a DC voltage regulator. Wouldn't connecting them introduce more noise into the system?

Comment: A stray transient needs to find its way back home - ie: current flows in a loop. Seems the transient goes back through your circuitry and upsets it. Plot the path through your 0V tracks from the load cell inputs back to the power supply.  Anything in this path may be affected. You need to provide a path to direct the transient away from your circuitry.

Comment: As an aside, hi-k capacitors tend to be piezo electric. You probably don’t want these in your loadcell signal path.

Comment: Also, as a matter of routing, I wouldn't run the coil signals directly on top of the contact ones, try not routing any traces following ones on another layer, cross them as close to 90 degrees as possible and route away.

Comment: You mentioned "a section of code that checks the intersample interval of the ADC (time between successive data ready interrupts). Should that interval be too long, the code checks the configuration registers and reinitializes the ADC if needed." One question for you: how are you reinitializing the ADC? I'm currently working with that ADC so I should know what you are talking about even if you don't describe it in detail. Thanks